# jquery flyout menu: make parent li stays same color when cursor moves to its sibling

Tags: jquery, menu, flyout

I have this [flyout menu](http://jsbin.com/acori/11) in which the "**2nd level menu 3**" is a flyout. The menu is generated by the CMS system so there is restriction to adding new classes directly to a specific menu item.

By default, the 1st level menu has a "**top-level**" class for anchor tag while 2nd and 3rd level don't have. What I want to achieve is **to target the "top-level" to find the "2nd level menu 3" to add a "current" class**, so that when flyout menu expanded, and cursor moves to the third level, the "2nd level menu 3" has the same white background color as the hover does.

The code is  **jQuery('#nav ul').find('> a.level-top').parent('li').addClass('current')});** but it's not working and I simply can't wrap my head to finding what I did wrong.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#nav li li").hover(function(){
        $(this).find('ul:first').css({visibility: "visible",display: "none"}).show(400);
        },function(){
        $(this).find('ul:first').css({visibility: "hidden"});
        });
    });
  $(document).ready(function(){
      jQuery('#nav ul').find('> a.level-top').parent('li').addClass('current')});
```

Answer (score 1):

get rid of your parent selector '>' in the find function.

I'd approach it more like

```
$('>li>ul>li').parent('ul>li').hover(function(){
    $(this).css(backgroundColor: 'red'
```

but before you do that buddy, your list code is mega messed. don't forget to close you list items, and if you're using a CMS that auto-generates this code then try something else :)

Comment: Thanks Harley, especially for the messy code. I handed with copy and pasted, validator didn't catch the error due to the cache I performed the first time when it was only two level deep.  but the code doesn't work. I tried removing the ">" as you suggested, and also tried yours method.  Your code use .hover; when the mouse moves to 3rd level, the second level ("2nd level menu 3") no longer at hover state is it not?